# ローカルの環境構築をしたいのですが、vagrant、virtualboxを使用して、RailsとPHPの2つの環境構築はできるのでしょうか？

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, vagrant, virtualbox

初心者エンジニアです。

ローカルの環境構築について教えてください。
vagrant、virtualboxを用いて、現在はRailsの開発環境(Rails、Ruby、PostgreSQL)を構築しているのですが、近々、PHPの業務があり、PHPの開発環境(PHP、MySQLなど)も構築する必要があります。

**教えて頂きたいこと**
1. PHPの環境を構築すると、Railsの環境が壊れないでしょうか？(ぐちゃぐちゃになるイメージです。)
2. vagrantを用いてvirtualbox内にRailsとPHPの2つの開発環境を構築することは可能なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

単一の仮想マシン (VM) 内に Rails と PHP を同居させることは可能です。
それは vagrant を使っているか否かには関係ありません。

具体的なディレクトリ構成やプロジェクト構成が書かれていないので一般論として回答すると以下のようになります。

> 1. PHPの環境を構築すると、Railsの環境が壊れないでしょうか？

PHP と Rails は独立しています。Rails を導入済みの環境に一般的な方法で PHP を導入したとしても、それだけで既存の Rails 環境が壊れることはありません。

> 2. vagrantを用いてvirtualbox内にRailsとPHPの2つの開発環境を構築することは可能なのでしょうか？

vagrant それ自体は単純に VM のイメージを取り込んだり起動したりするものであり、VM 内の環境構築は vagrant から呼び出されるスクリプトが制御します。
呼び出されるスクリプト（shellスクリプトや、chefやansible等のスクリプト）を正しく記述する限りにおいて、単一 VM 内に Rails と PHP を同居させることは可能です。

---

なお個人的には、両者を同一サーバー内で動作させなければならない、という要件でもない限り、Rails 用の VM と PHP 用の VM はそれぞれ別々に構築されることをお勧めします。